# Number pattern/ sequencing

Tags: sequences-and-series

A sequence is given by $U_m =2U_n - 1$ where m is $n+1$. $U_1=2$ for $n\geq1$.
Find the term of the sequence that has value 257.

Approach:

$U_m$=$2U_n - 1 = 257$

$U_n = 129$

$U_1 = 2$

$U_2 = 3$

$U_3 = 5$

$U_4 = 9$

$U_5 = 17$

Of course, if I continue to find the sequence for $U_n$, i will eventually found $U_8$ to be 129 and I can continue to find $U_m$ easily which is $U_9$.

I would like to know how can I find the answer more easily besides doing this, especially the value of the term gets even larger?

Comment: One technique is to take the differences of the numbers and see if you see a pattern. (which is basically the first approach in answering any "what's the next number in the sequence" problem)

Comment: Hint: $\;U_{n+1} \color{red}{-1} =2U_n - 1 \color{red}{-1}\,$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: see if you can spot a pattern in the sequence $U_n -1$

Comment: The difference between each term is 1, 2, 4, 8, 32 etc... which can also means 2^0, 2^1, 2^2, 2^3, 2^4 etc, so how can I further connect it with the term number?

Comment: @Joe - then just add the 1 back

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
d_n=U_{n+1}-U_{n} \quad \forall n\ge 1.
$$
Then $d_1=U_2-U_1=2U_1-1-U_1=1$ and for all $n\ge 1$ we have
$$
d_{n+1}=U_{n+2}-U_{n+1}=2U_{n+1}-2U_{n}=2d_n,
$$
i.e. $d_n$ is a geometric sequence. Therefore
$$
d_n=2^{n-1}d_1=2^{n-1}.
$$
Finally we have
\begin{eqnarray}
U_n&=&(U_n-U_{n-1})+(U_{n-1}-U_{n-2})+\cdots+(U_3-U_2)+(U_2-U_1)+U_1\cr
&=& U_1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(U_{i+1}-U_{i})\cr
&=&2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}d_i\cr
&=&2+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}2^{i-1}\cr
&=&2+\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k\cr
&=&2+\frac{1-2^{n-2+1}}{1-2}\cr
&=&2-(1-2^{n-1})\cr
\end{eqnarray}
Hence
$$
U_n=1+2^{n-1} \quad \forall n\ge 1.
$$
Notice that with this formula, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
U_1&=&2\cr
U_2&=&3\cr
&\vdots&\cr
U_8&=&129\cr
U_9&=&257\cr
U_{10}&=&513\cr
U_{11}&=&1025
\end{eqnarray}